# Modificar cada elemento de un array en una función Callback

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, bucles, callback

Llevo un par de semanas aprendiendo JavaScript y todo iba relativamente bien hasta que empezó a ir relativamente mal cuando me encontré con este ejercicio que no tengo muy claro cómo se resuelve:

El ejercicio me pide que haga una función que reciba por parámetro un `Array`, y que a cada elemento de ese `Array` se le añada, al inicio, un mismo texto.

Por ejemplo, si yo introduzco este array:

```js
["Argentina", "Brasil", "México"]
```

debería de devolverme algo así:

```js
["Selección de Argentina", "Selección de Brasil", "Selección de México"]
```

es decir, estoy añadiendo a cada elemento del `Array` original el texto "Selección de ".

Una vez que tenga esa función debo hacer uso de un `callback` para poder ejecutarla.

Intenté la siguiente aberración (pido una disculpa a los programadores que puedan estar leyendo esto) pero claramente, no funciona y me marca errores por todos lados:

```js
//Esta sería la función que agregaría los textos a cada elemento del array

function agregaTexto (unArray) {
    let textoModificado =1
    for (let i=0; i<= unArray.lenght; i ++){
        textoModificado= "Selección de "+ (textoModificado * unArray[i])
    }
    return textoModificado;

};

//Aquí haría un callback de la función 

let fraseCompleta = (unArray, agregaTexto) => agregaTexto(unArray)

//Y esto sería para correrla en la consola

console.log(fraseCompleta(["Alemania", "Brasil", "México"]), agregaTexto);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

No sé si se podría usar un `.push()`, un `indexOf` o algo más para agregar ese texto a cada elemento del array. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios errores en tu código, voy a tratar de explicar uno a uno:

Vas a devolver un arreglo, por lo que la definición de variable es incorrecta, en lugar de `1` debería ser `[]`

```
let textoModificado =1
```

La forma de establecer el ciclo:

```
for (let i=0; i<= unArray.lenght; i ++){
```

Es incorrecta, por dos razones:

1. En Javascript los índices de arreglos numéricos comienzan en cero y terminan en total de elementos menos uno. Al recorrer con `<= total de elementos`, la última iteración generará un error por índice no definido. Si tienes 3 elementos, debes recorrer de cero a 2 y basta con cambiar el signo a `<`
2. Tienes un error tipográfico, en vez de `lenght`, la propiedad correcta es `length`

Dentro del ciclo solo debes concatenar el texto deseado con el elemento que se está recorriendo e insertarlo al arreglo, pero no entiendo exactamente lo que intentas con esto:

```
textoModificado= "Selección de "+ (textoModificado * unArray[i])
```

Finalmente, estás enviando el nombre de la función a ejecutar como segundo parámetro de la consola y no de la función `fraseCompleta()`

```
console.log(fraseCompleta(["Alemania", "Brasil", "México"]), agregaTexto);
```

```js
//Esta sería la función que agregaría los textos a cada elemento del array
function agregaTexto (unArray) {
    // Debes devolver un arreglo
    let textoModificado = [];
    // Recorre mientras sea menor que length
    for (let i = 0; i < unArray.length; i ++){
        // Inserta un nuevo elemento, concatenando el texto
        textoModificado.push('Selección de ' + unArray[i]);
    }
    return textoModificado;

};

//Aquí haría un callback de la función
// Para dejar más claro, usa otro nombre de variable para la función callback
let fraseCompleta = (unArray, unaFuncion) => unaFuncion(unArray);

// El parámetro de función debe ir justo después del arreglo
console.log(fraseCompleta(["Alemania", "Brasil", "México"], agregaTexto));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

El código se puede simplificar un poco si usas el método [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) en lugar del ciclo, pero eso ya es otro tema.

Comment: Vaya... ¡qué buena respuesta! me sirvió a la perfección. Muchas gracias por explicar el código y señalar mis errores, me sirvió bastante :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, espero que te sirva

```
    var textoModificado = new Array();
    function AgregaTexto(unArray) {
    for (let i= 0; i< unArray.length; i++) {
    textoModificado[i] = 'Seleccion de ' + unArray[i];
    
    }
    return textoModificado;
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [answer]. Gracias por responder, sin embargo para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida, es necesario que expliques el código que has publicado. Responder sólo con código es considerado de baja calidad. Saludos

Comment: Lectura recomendada: [por qué es bueno explicar qué hace el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/).

Comment: @Hallen tu código me funcionó muy bien :) ¡gracias!